# convert sets to matrix: how can I do this efficiently in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a `JavaPairRDD` that contains the following pairs:

```
(key0, (a,d))
(key1, (c))
(key2, (b,d,e))
(key3, (a,c,d))
```

Now, I would like to accomplish the following:

1. combine all the values together (without worrying about the keys) to get the "universal space": `(a,b,c,d,e)`
2. convert each value into a vector by using a `1` to show the value contains that element from the universal space, and `0` otherwise. For example, the first value is `(a,d)`, it should be converted to `(1,0,0,1,0)`, the second value is `(c)`, it should therefore be converted to `(0,0,1,0,0)`, so on and so forth. When the conversion is done, I would be getting the following new pair RDD:

   ```
   (key0, (1,0,0,1,0))
   (key1, (0,0,1,0,0))
   (key2, (0,1,0,1,1))
   (key3, (1,0,1,1,0))
   ```

Can someone kindly tell me what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this by using Spark(Java)? any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some imports:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
```

Convert data to a `Dataset<Row>`:

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());


List<Tuple2<String, String[]>> data  = Arrays.asList(
        new Tuple2<>("key0", new String [] {"a", "d"}),
        new Tuple2<>("key1", new String [] {"c"}),
        new Tuple2<>("key2", new String [] {"b", "d", "e"}),
        new Tuple2<>("key3", new String [] {"a", "c", "d"})
);

JavaPairRDD<String, String[]> rdd = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(jsc.parallelize(data));

StructType schema = StructType.fromDDL("key string, value array<string>");


Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(
        rdd.map((Function<Tuple2<String, String[]>, Row>) value -> RowFactory.create(value._1(), value._2())),
        schema
);
```

And apply `CountVectorizer`

```java
CountVectorizer vectorizer = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("vector").setBinary(true);

vectorizer.fit(df).transform(df).show();
```

Result

```java
+----+---------+--------------------+
| key|    value|              vector|
+----+---------+--------------------+
|key0|   [a, d]| (5,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|
|key1|      [c]|       (5,[2],[1.0])|
|key2|[b, d, e]|(5,[0,3,4],[1.0,1...|
|key3|[a, c, d]|(5,[0,1,2],[1.0,1...|
+----+---------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because it indeed answered my question perfectly. Now, if I wanted to ask a follow-up/related new question, should I start a new question, or, should I just ask here?

Comment: It is better to ask a new question, unless of course, it is something that it is missing here.